# How to use multiple poetry environments for the same project?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-poetry

For my projects, I sometimes like to create different git branches which use different python packages to try and accomplish the same task so I can see which branch (i.e. which set of packages) I like using best. Correspondingly, I create separate environments for each branch.

I'm more familiar with Anaconda and the conda package manager tool, which allows for easy creation of multiple enviornments for a single project by just having separate .yml files for each environment, and activating / deactivating the environment names associated with each .yml file.

Is there a way to do something similar using poetry? From playing around with poetry and the docs I've read, poetry automatically recognizes a virtual environment when you are in a directory that you have initialized with poetry, and there is a single `poetry.lock` file for this environment. Would there be a way to do something like set up multiple `poetry.lock` files to have multiple poetry environments for a single project, and switch between them? Or if not, is there any other way in poetry to simulate the experience I describe using conda?

Comment: About "set up multiple `poetry.lock` files", I guess every branch could have its custom `poetry.lock`. Wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: ah yes, I guess this can work, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a brand new virtual environment or duplicate an existing one in poetry? (Multiple environment in a project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70739858/how-to-create-a-brand-new-virtual-environment-or-duplicate-an-existing-one-in-po)