# How to create a brand new virtual environment or duplicate an existing one in poetry? (Multiple environment in a project)

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-poetry

I have a project and an existing virtual environment created with poetry (**poetry install/init**).
So, as far as I know, the purpouse of a virtual environment is avoiding to modify the system base environment and the possibility of isolation (per project, per development, per system etc...).

**How can I create another brand new environment for my project in poetry? How can I eventually duplicate and use an existing one?**

I mean that **the current one (activated) should be not involved in this** (except for eventually copying it) because I want to test another set of dependencies and code.

I am aware of this:

- https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4055 (answer is not clear and ticket is not closed)
- https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-environments/ (use command seems not to work in the requested way)

Comment: For the *same* project you want to create a *different* environment? Why exactly? If you want to experiment with different dependencies, then `add`/`remove` them as necessary, which is all recorded in `poetry.lock`. When you're happy with your new dependencies, commit them to version control. If you're unhappy and want to roll back, roll back the lock file using version control and `poetry install` again. Basically, the lock file represents your environment; the actual environment created behind the scenes is somewhat irrelevant and disposable.

Comment: Hi deceze. I want to modify one or more dependencies (different version) and try how it works without loosing my original environment. Add and remove does not fit this. Update can do it, but I do not want to change the original environment that is actually working.

Comment: The point of poetry is that it can (supposedly) always re-create an exact working environment purely from a lock file. As long as you keep that lock file intact (preferably through version control), then adding or removing should not be of any concern.

Comment: @deceze On build agents, "globale" venvs may be around that I don't want to use or pollute.

Comment: Why not just clone your repository into a different folder, then you can trial with different dependencies in a completely new poetry virtual env.

Comment: Hmm, it's a shame that we can't have more than one venv per pyproject.toml without duplicating the repo. With the new addition of groups in 1.2.0, we can run commands like `poetry install --only <group_name>` to only install the dependencies of a defined group in e.g. CI without installing the whole application and its deps. But to test if these deps are enough on their own to do the job, we have to wipe the env and then install the groups deps? This seems like a missed opportunity with groups to me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Poetry seems to be **bound to one virtualenv per python interpreter**.
Poetry **is also bound to the pyproject.toml file and its path** to generate a new environment.

So there are 2 tricky solutions:

1 - change your deps in the pyproject.toml and **use another python version** (installed for example with pyenv) and then:

```
poetry env use X.Y
```

poetry will create a new virtual environment but this is not exactly the same as changing just some project deps.

2 - **use another pyproject.toml from another path**:

```
mkdir env_test
cp pyproject.toml env_test/pyproject.toml
cd env_test
nano pyproject.toml # edit your dependencies
poetry install # creates a brand new virtual environment
poetry shell
# run your script with the new environment
```

This will generate a new environment with just the asked dependencies changed. Both environments can be used at the same time.
After the test, it is eventually possible to delete the new environment with the env command.

Comment: Does not work for me as poetry seems stuck while trying to resolve dependencies

Comment: It works me, if you change the `name` under `[tool.poetry]` in pyproject.toml